# Why is Santa Claus a man but Santa Maria a woman?

Tags: etymology, christmas

When it comes to cities and boats named after saints, it seems that "Santa" is always female and "San" is always male.

> *e.g.*
>
> **Male Saints**: San Diego, San Francisco, San Antonio
>
> **Female Saints**: Santa Barbara, Santa Maria

So why isn't "Santa Claus" a woman like all the other "Santa"s?

Comment: Is this anything about the English language?

Comment: I think so. English speakers call him "Santa Claus", don't they. It just has foreign origins.

Comment: I think [the etymology of Santa Claus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus) is General Reference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But that's not the question. The question is why it does not conform to the same naming conventions of other saints.

Comment: For one thing, isn’t Santa Claus an elf not a man? :) More seriously, on the *san/santa* bit, consider ***Santo** Domingo*. It isn’t always *San*; see my comment below.

Comment: @Urbycoz: It certainly seems to me that Wikipedia article answers your question. As does etymonline's [*from dialectal Dutch **Sante Klaas**, from Middle Dutch **Sinter Niklaas** "Saint Nicholas,"*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Santa+Claus). It doesn't conform to modern-day Spanish usage because it didn't *come* directly from Spanish.

Comment: This question, for a fraction of a second, broke my universe.

Comment: Are you talking about the place in [Arizona, Georgia, or Indiana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus_(disambiguation))?

Comment: @tchrist You still have any doubt?

Comment: @FumbleFingers My point is that your links only answer part of the question- It explains that "Santa" in Santa Claus comes from the Dutch. It doesn't explain why it is different to the other "Santa" saints.

Comment: @Urbycoz: It seems to me that since we adopted *Santa Claus* from Dutch, not Spanish, there's no particular reason why our usage should follow Spanish gender conventions. Perhaps what you *really* want to know is "Why did the **Dutch** not call him **Sin Niklaas** in the first place?" But that would presumably be Off Topic here.

Comment: I preferred your original title. Please change it back, I know it stings to have your question closed but you got a really great amount of deserved attention and an excellent answer to boot.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I'll leave my new title. I think it addresses the real question I'm asking here and prevents the "half-answers" that my original title attracted. And I agree with the question closure- I didn't notice the duplicate answer.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The city names you quote are all derived from Spanish, where "San" (or "Santo", as @tchrist clarifies below) is the male inflection and "Santa" the female one. However, Santa Claus isn't derived from Spanish, but from Dutch, where it was originally rendered as *Sante Klaas*, and was modified to Santa when it was adopted into English (and from English, to the rest of the world). Here's [Etymonline's](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Santa%20Claus&allowed_in_frame=0) take on it:

> from dialectal Dutch **Sante Klaas**, from Middle Dutch **Sinter Niklaas** "Saint Nicholas,"

English, like all other languages, borrows words from many sources, and they often carry over remnants of their original grammar or usage, even when it makes for inconsistent usage in English.

Comment: so there is no connection between this san and santas? that is widely famous saints?

Comment: He is now Sinterklaas here

Comment: Both the Spanish *San/Santa* and the Dutch *Sante/Sinter* are ultimately derived from the same root, probably Latin and borrowed by Dutch and German at some point in the past.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: from latin sanctus, meaning holy (sanctuary = a place to keep holy things)

Comment: That’s a wee bit of a simplification: *san* is not guaranteed for males. Although [the Spanish word *santo* usually apocopates to *san* before a man’s name](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santo#Empleo_del_t.C3.A9rmino), this shortening does **not** occur when the saint’s name starts with *To-* or *Do-*. For example, the correct forms of the saints’ names, and where it applies, therefore also the cities’, are: *Santo Tomé, Santo Toribio, Santo Tomás, y Santo Domingo*. There are a few other historical exceptions, which you can find [here](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Santoral_cat%C3%B3lico).

Comment: “(and from English, to the rest of the world)” — That’s a bit of an exaggeration, surely? Obviously, I don’t speak every language in the world, but in the ones I do speak, Japanese サンタクロース _santakurōsu_ is the only English-based one. In the rest he’s called _julemanden_, _jultomten_, _julenissen_, _jólasveinninn_, _joulupukki_ (all ‘Christmas man/elf/mythological thingy’), _père Noël_, _papá noel_,  _daidí na Nollag_ (all ‘Father Christmas’), _άγιος Βασίλης_ (‘Saint Basil’),  圣诞老人 (‘Old Man Christmas’), etc. Looking at the Wiktionary article, it does seem that a fair few languages that don’t →

Comment: → have traditional words for Christmas and belong in parts of the world where Christmas is not traditionally celebrated have borrowed the English word… but to say that it spread to ‘the rest of the world’ seems a bit much.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Only if you take the maximalist interpretation of "spread" to mean "overrun" and "rest of the world" to mean "every single country". (-:

Answer (score 2):

You can check the following links for references.

[Sinterklaas (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinterklaas)

('Saint Nicholas') is a traditional winter holiday figure celebrated in various regions of Europe, including: the Netherlands, Belgium and Luxembourg, some parts of Germany and Austria, (Sankt Nikolaus); Switzerland (Samichlaus), Italy (San Nicola in Bari, South Tyrol, Alpine municipalities, and many others), French Flanders, Lorraine and Artois, the Balkans, Greece. Other names for the figure include De Sint ('The Saint'), or more formally Sint Nicolaas or Sint Nikolaas; Saint-Nicolas in French; Sankt Nikolaus in German, also known as De Goedheiligman ('The Good Holy Man')

He is one of the sources of the holiday figure of Santa Claus in North America.

[Saint Nicholas (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Nicholas)

I think after reading these references, your doubt will be cleared forever :)